# What are some good headphones for running

Tags: headphones

I'm looking for really great headphones with really great construction for running but can't find it.

I try new headphones every month or so, but the only ones I can find are low quality with a really bad fastening system.

Comment: This isn't really a question about "Audio Recording & Production." What you are looking for is a general audiophile site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like [Sony's low end headphones](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_p_36_5?bbn=172282&keywords=sony+headphones&qid=1303824549&rh=n%3A172282%2Ck%3Asony+headphones&rnid=386442011&low-price=&high-price=10&x=9&y=11).  They usually sell for around $10 usd and sound pretty good.

Since you will be running with them, I recommend the [type that hook on your ear](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000092YR6).  I haven't done much running with them, but I have done lots of yard work without any issues.  They have a nice clear full sound, though they are a bit weaker on the low end than some of the [other models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005N6KG).